# Resizing / partition tricky setup

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted, swap, system

I have some experience with running Ubuntu and am currently rocking 14.04, but I seem to have messed up the partition table a bit this time around. This came to my attention as I was looking into resizing my system partition (/). I realized there is no swap and it looks strange.

1. How do I figure out what the extended partition sda5 is up to? In information Gparted says it is unable to detect file system.
2. What would be the best option to resize partition sda1?
3. Would it be adviceable to set up a swap?

[Gparted Partition List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwnB4.png)

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend 20 GB for /. sda5 was probably your swap partition, check your /etc/fstab to see why it isn't mounting.

Comment: Well you first need to identify the unknown partition, could be a crypt or LVM. gparted may not be able to resize or move unknown partitions, you man need to do it manually.

Comment: To resize you need to move the unpartitioned free space adjacent to the partition you want to enlarge and you need to do it in steps. resize -> apply changes -> move -> apply changes . The extended partition included, so resize sda3 -> apply changes -> move sda3 -> apply changes -> move sda2 -> apply changes. You may need to manually first enlarge sda2 -> apply changes -> move sda6 -> apply changes -> move sda5 -> apply changes -> resize sda2 -> apply changes

Comment: Really truely... it IS a messed up layout... you need to backup your data, use `gparted` to lay down a fresh partition table (which will wipe the disk), and reinstall Ubuntu with `erase and install` (don't use any funky partitioning... take the Ubuntu default), then restore your data. You'll be much happier in the long run. (ps: sda5 used to be swap).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems the easiest and least time consuming option is a full wipe and new install. I guess I knew it when I first laid eyes on the problem, but don't we all wish for a quick fix sometimes. And of course, I shall back up my data.